# IOS showing App running in background after running out of battery

Tags: ios

I have an iOS application that monitors the user location in the background and sends to a remote server. The locations are stored in a local SQLite database and transmitted when network is available.

I have added code to store an 'Application Exit' event in the local SQLite database within 'applicationWillTerminate'. This catches when either iOS or the user terminate the app. This event is then sent to the the server the next time the app is run.

I have observed that sometimes when the phone runs out of battery and shuts down, it will resume in the background when the phone is powered up again, and sometimes it won't.

In the situations where it does not resume, I can see that the application was terminated.

I understand this bit, as the operating system is presumably killing apps to conserve battery.

My question is that regardless of whether the app was terminated, it will still show as a background application (double tap the iphone button) regardless of whether it is running in the background when the phone is restarted after the charger is reconnected. I can't find any documentation on this behaviour, is it expected?

My main issue is the app looks like it is running in the background when it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not just a list of running apps, but also a history. They remain as apps may get terminated for memory reasons and should still be visible so they can be available to a user to select.

Apple support here says:

Double-click the Home button to display recently used apps.

http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202070

Comment: Thanks, shows what I know about iPhones. A good blog article here too: http://www.speirs.org/blog/2012/1/2/misconceptions-about-ios-multitasking.html